# Nested route in resource not being accesible by Link-To

Tags: ember.js

I can't make it work. The problem lies in the `projects` route, `notes` and `info` routes are not being linked

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'}, function(){
      this.route('info', { path: "/info"});
      this.route('notes', { path: "/notes"});
    });
  });
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});
```

The `project` template making the call to `project_notes.hbs` and `project_info.hbs` is as follows.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">{{title}}</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>{{#link-to 'project.Info' project}}Info{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to 'project.Notes' project}}Notes{{/link-to}}</li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

After reading [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) I was able to go a step further but still it's not working. Let me know if you need more info like the `project` model or anything.

### Error

```
This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.
```

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

The route is `ProjectInfoRoute` which is fine, the pointing URL is `/projects/:project_id/info` which is also absolutely fine. But when I click in the `Project` in order to go to Project/Project_id now it says `There is no route named info.index`

This is defining `info` as a `this.route` if I use `this.resource` it's like the route for `info` gets twisted since it's `InfoRoute` instead of `ProjectInfoRoute`. (If I go for the resource, after getting into the project template, I click on `info` and I can't get to see that template.) I'm scratching my head here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send it, additionally it should be link-to should be lower case

```
<ul class="nav">
{{#if model}}
      <li>{{#link-to 'project.info' model}}Info{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to 'project.notes' model}}Notes{{/link-to}}</li>  
{{else}}
    do some other menu here, go to projects, or something
{{/if}}
</ul>
```

additionally you can find out the scope and values of properties really easy by tossing them into the template or logging them

```
{{project}}
{{log project}}
{{log model}}
{{log this}}
```

Comment: It's always going through the `{{else}}` like it's not a project model. Funny thing is that `{{title}}` is fine, so it's getting the item but not like a `project model`. After checking ember inspector I do see that the model is an `App.Project:emberXXXXX` so it is the right model... Only weird thing is the controller, it says `Ember.ObjectController` instead of `Ember.ProjectController` Any idea? Thanks a lot. btw this is how I link to the project template `{{#link-to 'project' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}} `

Comment: oh, sorry, I assumed project was the name of the property, send in the model.

Comment: still not working, I edited the question. If you can't follow me it's fine! I've gone pretty far after your directions! thanks

Comment: believe it or not, I was able to fix this using the {{log}} trick. As usual, you saved me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I totally believe it, the logging from the template is so helpful.